# Execute and run notepad on remote computer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, powershell

When I run the following code notepad open on my local computer as it should:

```
Invoke-Command {Invoke-Expression '&"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"'}
```

When I add **-computername** to the code and provide my  local computer name I get an access is denied message.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computername {Invoke-Expression '&"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"'}
```

Not sure where to go from here. The sites I have look at provide examples for local computers.

I would like to open notepad in a remote computer.

Regards,

Comment: Even if you're logged into the remote PC, it wont run in your session it will run in a specific session for the remote command.. what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Remote computer requires credentials. You will have to pass the `-Credential` argument. Other than that, the result will be different than you might expect. Notepad process will start, but you will not see the application itself. The reason for it is that there might be no one logged in on the remote computer, or multiple people logged in, who to show application to?

If you want to actually show the application in the user session, you first need to get the session Id and then use tool like PSexec, or PAexec to do it, but it's a very bad practice.

Comment: The same user is always logged on to the computer 24/7. Yes, I would like notepad to open when I execute the PowerShell code. Don't want to user PSexece. Thanks.

Comment: @lmalave : Any reason you don't want to use `psexec`? You can also use [WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31113/Create-a-Remote-Process-using-WMI-in-C).

Comment: It's in the gray are of windows, so do not expect it to be easy, or reliable. Here's some more info: http://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: Visual Vincent- I will deploy my winform with the codes to many users, trying to keep it just PS within C# in WINFORMS.

Comment: @lmalave : Eh, why use PowerShell at all if you can use WMI or other native solutions?

Comment: So why exactly do you need to start the application? Can't your users start it themselves? For deploying the application you don't need UI

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get invoke-command to work with notepad, but this does work

`Invoke-WmiMethod –ComputerName servername -Class win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "notepad"`

Answer (score 0):

Create batch file #1 or execute from cmd:

```
call StartRemoteApp.bat userid IpOrServerName userid password
```

Create batch file StartRemoteApp.bat and place code below in it:

```
@echo off 

REM This program gets remote session info on a given server, for a given user.
REM It needs 4 parameters: UserName, ServerName, Login, Password

REM For a local session, simply replace the 'psexec \\...' command parsed by the 'for'
REM loop with: 'query session ^| find /i "%UserName%"'
REM In that case, only the UserName parameter is necessary to call this batch.

set UserName=%1
set ServerName=%2
set Login=%3
set Password=%4

set SessionName=
set SessionUser=
set SessionId=
set SessionState=

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=^> " %%a in ('psexec \\%ServerName% -u %Login% -p %Password% query session ^| find /i "%UserName%"') do (

    REM Test iterator because a disconnected session may no longer have a name!

    if /I "%%b"=="%UserName%" (
        set SessionName=%%a
        set SessionUser=%%b
        set SessionId=%%c
        set SessionState=%%d
    )

    if /I "%%a"=="%UserName%" (
        set SessionName=[unknown]
        set SessionUser=%%a
        set SessionId=%%b
        set SessionState=%%c
    )
  )

echo Session info:
echo - Name:  %SessionName%
echo - User:  %SessionUser%
echo - ID:    %SessionId%
echo - State: %SessionState%

psexec \\%ServerName% -u %Login% -p %Password% -i %SessionId% -d notepad.exe
REM psexec \\%ServerName% -u %Login% -p %Password% -i %SessionId% -d "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe"

PAUSE
```